# How to create folder and text file in Jenkins common location

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

We would like to create a folder in Jenkins commons location, this folder should be accessible for all Jenkins Job and builds. We will be creating one text file for each build in this central location. Can someone please suggest in Jenkins where we can create this kind of folder. We don't want to created in our Jenkins build work space - this folder location should be outside of Jenkins build workspace.

How can we achieve this - it would be really appreciated if someone can help us on this.

Comment: You can access the entire jenkins home dir (probably /var/lib/jenkins). Because in the end it will just boil down to whether the jenkins user has permissions to write to that location.

Answer (score 0):

We are facing the same requirements, and we realized it by using a path to the file server.

Here some examples of our code:

```
// create new project file
new File("//<PATH_TO_YOUR_FILE_SERVER>/JenkinsCommon/${JOB_NAME}.txt").createNewFile()
new File("//<PATH_TO_YOUR_FILE_SERVER>/JenkinsCommon/${JOB_NAME}.txt").write("${ContentOfYourVariable}")    
// read content from project file
String ProjectFileContent  = new File("//<PATH_TO_YOUR_FILE_SERVER>/JenkinsCommon/${JOB_NAME}.txt").text
```

Does this help you or is it necessary to create the folder directly on your master?

Answer (score 0):

I think for this requirement someone developed the [External Workspace Manager Plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/external-workspace-manager-plugin/blob/master/README.md)

=> This plugin provides an external workspace management system. It facilitates workspace share and reuse across multiple Jenkins jobs. It eliminates the need to copy, archive or move files.